# How to run .jar file?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, javafx, jar

I made a program to calculate "Attestation de vacances", it's not important what it is, but i coded it on IntelliJ idea with use of javafx. Everything works perfectly in intelliJ but when i build it into a .jar file it doesn't work. Why? I'm searching whole day for sollution and i did everything i found on the internet. Right now i'm trying to run it on cmd console but i'm getting this error "Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application.". Once again... I was looking for it on the internet and i've tried multiple methods to repair this so i'm assuming that everything with it is okay and this errer pops up just because yes, and the program doesn't work because no. So once again i ask, how tf do i run .jar file? Isn't it a double click? Maybe it's triple click then? Or a toe click or i dunno...

Comment: Well you could use [maven shade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/maven-shade-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing), which is unsupported.  Or you could use the [javafx maven plugin to jlink the app](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin#javafxjlink-options).  Further instructions are in the runtime image section of the getting started instructions at openjfx.io.  There are also hundreds of questions on this on this site.

Comment: Note that error typically means your main class is a subclass of `javafx.application.Application` but the `javafx.graphics` module was not found in the boot module layer. JavaFX only technically supports being loaded as named modules. That, for a few reasons, means that executable JAR files are not really supported for JavaFX applications, especially if you're trying to create a so-called fat/uber/shaded JAR file. It's possible to have an executable JAR file, but that basically means having a JDK/JRE (which could have been created via `jlink`) that includes JavaFX in the run-time image.

Comment: There are quite a few links under the "Packaging" section of the [JavaFX tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info) if you want some deployment ideas. Also check out https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Answer (score 1):

Can you share a some of the code you are using?

You'll need to make sure to specify the main class (usually META-INF/MANIFEST.MF), specify the main class for your application. The manifest should contain a line like this:

```
Main-Class: com.yourpackage.YourMainClass
```

You'll also want to run the JAR file with JavaFX

```
java --module-path /path/to/javafx-sdk/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar YourApp.jar
```

`/path/to/javafx-sdk/lib` should point to the lib directory of your JavaFX SDK installation.

Comment: I did, my manifest has line "Main-Class: org.example.Main", it's correct main class because i don't have any other, and for the javafx my program works when i don't use VM Options with "java --module-path /path/to/javafx-sdk/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar YourApp.jar" but when i try to apply it, then my program stops working in intelliJ idea aswell. But thanks for trying to help!

Comment: And even if i run jar file with javafx it's still not working

Comment: Hmm – then it might the Project Language Level doesn't match the Java Version –– or the project compiler isn't pointing to the correct output directory for compiled classed, or the Project SDK needs to be set differently.